# Does this ODE have non trivial periodic orbits?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am dealing with the following system of differential equations, where $\alpha,\beta$ are two angles of a triangle (so I'm only interested in the region $\alpha,\beta\geq0,\alpha+\beta\leq\pi$):

$$\alpha'=-\frac{\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2}+\beta)\sin(\alpha)}{\sin(\beta/2)\cos(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})}$$

$$\beta'=\frac{\cos(\frac{\beta}{2}+\alpha)\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\alpha/2)\cos(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})}$$

After representing it in Mathematica (see the program and vector plot below), I find it likely that the solution of the differential equation is composed by closed orbits surrounding the point $(\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{3})$. The easiest way I know to prove that is to find a function $H:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{\partial H}{\partial \alpha}\alpha'+\frac{\partial H}{\partial \beta}\beta'=0$ (so that $H$ is invariant along the orbits of the differential equation). However I haven't found anything like that.

I am looking for any kind of help with understanding the behaviour of this differential equation, including proving whether the orbits are periodic or not, by any method.

[image]

Comment: The phase portrait has a symmetry with respect to the line $\alpha=\beta$, so it should be possible to make an argument to the effect that an orbit connecting $(c,c)$ to $(d,d)$ on one side of that line must “do the same thing on the other side of the line” so that it connects $(d,d)$ back to $(c,c)$.

Comment: (And of course that symmetry comes from the symmetric way that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ appear in the ODEs; it's not just something that “happens to *look* symmetric”.)

Comment: Thanks! I think I see how to make that work. Of course there is still some work to do, mostly proving that the orbit of a point $(d,d)$ actually reaches some point $(c,c)$. But that should not be difficult